# Iterating through UITextViews within a tableview using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview, option-type

I'm currently learning how to build apps entirely programatically and have hit a bit of a wall in the process.

My app is going to be a fairly simple form that the user can fill in and it will generate a PDF at the end containing the information. For the basic information I have a tableview containing a set of UITextfields and have no problem iterating through them and extracting the data into an array of strings. 
For the next section the user needed to input a lot more text so I have used UITextviews within the tableview. What I want to be able to do is extract the text inputted and save it to an array of strings that is used to create my customer object. The code that does this is as follows:

```
func createGoals() {
   for section in 0..<secondTableView.numberOfSections {

        for row in 0..<secondTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section) {

            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: row, section: section)
            let thisCell = secondTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! mySecondCell
                if thisCell.textview.text == "Enter Goals" {
                print("NO CONTENT IN FIELD")
                let ac = UIAlertController(title: "But...But...", message: "If you have no goals, how can you progress?!", preferredStyle: .alert)
                ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                present(ac, animated: true)
                break
                }  else {
                    print("I MADE IT")
                    print("\(thisCell.textview.text!)")
                    newClient.goalArray.append(thisCell.textview.text)
                    print(newClient.goalArray)
                    }
        }
    }

}
```

But when this runs I get the error message "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" and it particularly highlights this line:

```
let thisCell = secondTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! mySecondCell
```

This code is almost identical to how I iterate through the UITextfields successfully, all thats changed is the variables attached and as far as I can see there are no optionals.
Also if I don't fill in the UITextviews it will show the UIAlertController, it only seems to have a problem when I remove the placeholder and fill in the UITextviews.
Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening? I can provide more of my code if needed.

Comment: Debugger is telling you that secondTableView does not contains any cell at the row you passed. Verifying the row count of secondTableView should help.

Comment: I've just tried in the debugger and it is returning 4 rows in section 0 which is as expected. The rows are definitely there, so could my for loop somehow miss one?

Comment: `mySecondCell` seems an instance, not a class. You need to get the cell as a class type ie. `let thisCell = secondTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCellSubclass` or even better using a guard `guard let thisCell = secondTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as? mySecondCell else { return }`

Answer (score 0):

Here is your optional

```
as! mySecondCell
```

Obviously, `thisCell` isn't a `mySecondCell`

Check if you did register the correct class

**EDIT**

You shouldn't call delegate method by yourself

Comment: Oh I didn't realise that still counted as an optional I thought forced downcasts were different. Here is how I have registered it, I'm pretty sure it's right?

Within VDL:
    'secondTableView.delegate = self
        secondTableView.dataSource = self
        secondTableView.register(mySecondCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "secondCellID")',

Also in the cellForRow:

    'if tableView == self.secondTableView {
            let bCell = secondTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "secondCellID", for: indexPath) as! mySecondCell',

This is the correct way to register right?

Comment: You might be right. I didn't pay attention to where you were using this piece of code. You should read Kalpesh jetani's answer. He's right, you can't call delegate method by yourself

Answer (score 0):

here you are loading cell in iteration. so issue is caused because you are going to load/access cell which is not visible.

here you should not load cell out side of cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Reason: *UITableView is reusing cell with reusableCellIdentifier*.

here you need to save values in array or dictionary when textfield-didEndEditing called (textfield delegate method).
and for validation check you can use saved value from array/dictionary.

Comment: Ok brilliant I will try it that way and see.
Just out of interest is there any reason that loading the cell within the iteration works perfectly when iterating through textFields but not when using textViews?

Comment: if it is working with textFields then it should work with textViews when it it not weak.

if you iterate tableview.visiblecells  you will not get above issue. but here your task is not complete. so for getting modified values from textviews/Textfields you need to save it on didEndEditing. 

still there is issue, please check category/extenstion Or super class.